# Output issues in java program

Tags: java

Ok so this program is trying to display the middle digit of a 1-4 digit integer and if it has an even number of digits it should display that there is no middle digits, however I can't get it to output the answer properly, here is the code:

```
public class digit {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int MyInt1, MyInt2, MyInt3, MyInt4;
        EasyReader keyboard = new EasyReader();
        // Get the 1-4 digit integer
        int MyInt = keyboard.readInt("Enter your integer: ");
        // Calculate the middle digit
        MyInt1=MyInt/10;
        if (MyInt1 < 1) {
            System.out.print("The middle digit is: ");
            System.out.println(MyInt);
        MyInt2=MyInt1/10;
        }else if (MyInt2 < 1) {
            System.out.println("No middle digit");
        MyInt3=MyInt2/10;
        }else if (MyInt3 < 1) {
            System.out.print("The middle digit is: ");
            System.out.println(MyInt2);
        MyInt4=MyInt3/10;
        }else if (MyInt4 < 1) {
            System.out.println("No middle digit");
        }   
    }
}
```

I also import a package at the start.

An example output I get is if I enter 1234 as the integer I get: '123412No middle digit' as my answer, I must be doing something wrong with the else if statements I think but I don't know what it is. Help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Indentation doesn't define what's executed and what isn't executed with `if` statements.

If you don't satisfy the first condition, `MyInt2` will never be defined, so the next condition will also fail.  In your original code, if `MyInt1 < 1` is true, then you will print `The middle digit is:` and  calculate the value of `MyInt2`.  If, however, the condition is false you will check if `MyInt2 < 1`, but `MyInt2` is undefined, since it's only calculated (in your original code) when the first condition is true.

Something like this should work:

```
// Calculate the middle digit
MyInt1=MyInt/10;
MyInt2=MyInt1/10;
MyInt3=MyInt2/10;
MyInt4=MyInt3/10;
if (MyInt1 < 1) {
    System.out.print("The middle digit is: ");
    System.out.println(MyInt);
}else if (MyInt2 < 1) {
    System.out.println("No middle digit");
}else if (MyInt3 < 1) {
    System.out.print("The middle digit is: ");
    System.out.println(MyInt2);
}else if (MyInt4 < 1) {
    System.out.println("No middle digit");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PrintMiddleDigit {
  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    EasyReader keyboard = new EasyReader();
    int number = keyboard.readInt("Enter your integer: ");
    String str = String.valueOf(number);
    if (str.length() % 2 == 0) {
      System.out.println("No middle digit");
    } else {
      int middle = str.length() / 2;
      System.out.print("The middle digit is: ");
      System.out.println(str.charAt(middle));
    }
  }
}
```

Some remarks:

- Class names are usually written in `UpperCamelCase`, variable names in `lowerCamelCase`.
- The middle digit is easier to extract from the string that represents the number.
- The expression `str.length() / 2` will always round towards zero.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Give an integer number from 1 to 4 digits: ");
String number = input.next();


switch(input.length())
{
    case 3:
       System.out.println("The middle is " + input[1]);
       break;
    case 4:
       System.out.println("The middles are " + input[1] + " " + input[2]);
       break;
    default:
       System.out.println("You are inserted wrong number, there aren't middles");
}
```